# Recargar Datatable después de confirmación HTML, PHP, JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, datatables

**

Hola buen dia, quería saber si se puede "recargar" una tabla implementada con el plugin `Datatables` sin tener que recargar la pagina.

Tengo una tabla con una columna de "Acciones" que tiene dos , uno para editar la información de esa persona y otro para activar/desactivar el estatus de esa persona. Lo que quiero es que al `activar/desactivar` a esa persona me `recargue` la tabla y cambie el icono que le asigne a ese `<a></a>` sin tener que actualizar la pagina manualmente (F5).
Hasta ahora mi solución fue poner un                             `window.location.href="mismapagina";` para simular eso, pero no me parece correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Al presionar el icono activar/desactivar puse una ventana de confirmación utilizando sweetAlert2.js donde si es true, ejecuto el `window.location`, sino no hago nada.

LISTADO HTML:

```html
<section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box">

            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="registros" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="10%">Acciones</th>
                  <th>Materia</th>
                  <th>Creditos</th>
                  <th>Cuatrimestre</th>
                  <th width="10%">Estatus</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                try{
                    $sql="SELECT idmateria, nombre, creditos, siglas, idcuatrimestre, estatus from materia order by idcuatrimestre, idmateria asc ";
                    $resultado=$conn->query($sql);
                }catch (Exception $e){
                    $error = $e->getMessage();
                    echo $error;
                }
                while ($admin=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%">
                            <a href="editar-materias.php?id=<?php echo $admin['idmateria'];?>" class="btn bg-orange mb btn-flat ">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($admin['estatus']){ ?>
                                <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $admin['idmateria']?>;" data-tipo="materia" title="Desactivar usuario" class="btn bg-green-gradient mb  btn-flat  desactivar_registro">
                                    <i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i>
                                </a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $admin['idmateria']?>;" data-tipo="materia" title="Activar usuario" class="btn bg-gray mb  btn-flat  activar_registro">
                                    <i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>


                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $admin['nombre'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $admin['creditos'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $admin['idcuatrimestre'];?></td>
                        <?php if ($admin['estatus']){ ?>
                            <td width="10%"><span class="label bg-green-active">ACTIVO</span></td>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td width="10%"><span class="label bg-gray-active">INACTIVO</span></td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>


                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                    <th>Materia</th>
                    <th>Creditos</th>
                    <th>Cuatrimestre</th>
                    <th width="10%">Estatus</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
```

Codigo Datatable (Este codigo lo puse en un .js aparte porque lo reutilizo para todas las tablas que tengo, todas tienen el mismo id):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registros').dataTable({
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel',
            {
                extend      : 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation : 'landscape',
                pageSize    : 'LEGAL'
            }
        ],
        'paging'      : true,
        'lengthChange': true,
        'searching'   : true,
        'ordering'    : true,
        'info'        : true,
        'autoWidth'   : false,
        'language'    :{
            sProcessing:     "Procesando...",
            sLengthMenu:     "Mostrar   _MENU_ registros",
            sZeroRecords:    "No se encontraron resultados",
            sEmptyTable:     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            sInfo:           "Mostrando _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            sInfoEmpty:      "Mostrando _END_ de un total de 0 registros",
            sInfoFiltered:   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            sInfoPostFix:    "",
            sSearch:         "Buscar:",
            sUrl:            "",
            sInfoThousands:  ",",
            sLoadingRecords: "Cargando...",
            oPaginate: {
                sFirst:    "Primero",
                sLast:     "Último",
                sNext:     "Siguiente",
                sPrevious: "Anterior"
            },
            oAria: {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

        },

    }).DataTable();
    $('#registros').wrap("<div class='scrolledTable'></div>");
});
```

Código activar/desactivar:

```js
function activarRegistro() {
    $('.activar_registro').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');

        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = swal.mixin({
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: true,
        })

        swalWithBootstrapButtons({
            title: '¿Activar usuario?',
            text: "Activara el usuario seleccionado",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Activar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            reverseButtons: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'id': id,
                        'registro' : 'activar'
                    },
                    url: '../funciones/modelo-'+tipo+'.php',
                    success: function(e) {
                        var resultado = JSON.parse(e);
                        if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
                            swal(
                                '¡Activado!',
                                'El usuario ha sido activado.',
                                'success'
                            )
                            // jQuery('[data-id="'+ resultado.id_eliminado +'"]').parents('tr').remove();
                            window.location.href="listado-alumnos.php";
                        }else{
                            swal(
                                '¡Error!',
                                'El usuario no se pudo activar',
                                'error'
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log("Error: "+e.responseText);
                    }

                })
            } else if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
            ) {
                swalWithBootstrapButtons(
                    'Cancelado',
                    'No se realizó ningún cambio',
                    'error'
                )
            }
        })

    });
}

function desactivarRegistro() {
    $('.desactivar_registro').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');

        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = swal.mixin({
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: true,
        })

        swalWithBootstrapButtons({
            title: '¿Desactivar usuario?',
            text: "Desactivara el usuario seleccionado",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Desactivar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            reverseButtons: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'id': id,
                        'registro' : 'desactivar'
                    },
                    url: '../funciones/modelo-'+tipo+'.php',
                    success: function(e) {
                        var resultado = JSON.parse(e);
                        if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
                            swal(
                                '¡Desactivado!',
                                'El usuario ha sido desactivado.',
                                'success'
                            )
                            window.location.href="listado-alumnos.php";
                        }else{
                            swal(
                                '¡Error!',
                                'El usuario no se pudo desactivar',
                                'error'
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log("Error: "+e.responseText);
                    }

                })
            } else if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
            ) {
                swalWithBootstrapButtons(
                    'Cancelado',
                    'No se realizó ningún cambio',
                    'error'
                )
            }
        })

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema parecido con DataTable solo que para realizar una búsqueda, la solución fue, en el `success`

1. "Destruir la tabla"
2. Llamar la respuesta de ajax
3. Volver a construir la tabla.

ejemplo.

```
success: function (respuesta) {
        /*Destruimos la tabla*/
        $("#registros").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        //*Mostramos la respuesta en la tabla*//
        $('#registros').html(respuesta);

          /*Se crea la tabla nuevamente*/
        $('#registros').DataTable({
            "info": true,
            "searching": true
        });
    }
```

con esto se debería poder ver los cambios en el DataTable sin necesidad de recargar la pagina.

Comment: Al activar/desactivar destruye la tabla pero no la crea y manda este error en consola: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

Comment: Es importante que su THEAD no esté vacío en la tabla. El dataTable requiere que especifique el número de columnas de los datos esperados. Según sus datos debería de ser <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="10%">Acciones</th>
                  <th>Materia</th>
                  <th>Creditos</th>
                  <th>Cuatrimestre</th>
                  <th width="10%">Estatus</th>
                </tr>
                </thead> en su archivo "modelo-'+tipo+'.php"

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar que te parece llenar tu tabla con un archivo `php` aparte de esta manera

```
var table = $('#registros').DataTable({
  // Otra configuracion
  ajax: {
    url: 'archivo.php'
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'Acciones' },
    { data: 'Materias' },
    { data: 'Creditos' },
    { data: 'Cuatrimestres' },
    { data: 'Estatus' }
  ]
});
```

EL archivo `php`estaria respondiendo de esta manera

```
// Tu consulta
$data = array();
if ($result) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

Ahora para tu etiqueta de estatus se ocupara render que al recargar la pagina puedes colocar una condicional que evaluara y de acuerdo al dato mostrara la etiqueta correspondiente.

```
function setEstatus(data, type, row, meta) {    
    let xClass = "",
        msg    = "";
    if(data){
        xClass = "green"
        msg    = "ACTIVO"
    }else{
        xClass = "gray"
        msg    = "ACTIVO"
    }
    return data = `<span class="label bg-${xClass}-active">${msg}</span>`;    
}
```

Y asi para poder decirle a dataTable que ocupe  tu render en una columna seria de esta manera

```
{ data: 'Estatus' ,render: setEstatus}
```

Con esto en tu funcion activar y desactivar registro le haras un refresh ala tabla cargara los nuevos datos y render hara lo suyo, espero no haberte enredado y ojala te funcione